# Get URL parts in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to get my all url parts after "/". Example:

```
http://myadress.com/#/example/url/here/param1

Result: ['example', 'url', 'here'].
```

But `$routeParams` returns only object with route parameters `{param1: 'param1'}`

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take url parts like this

```
var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
```

to get result from string.

```
var secondLevelLocation = pathArray[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative to Jo_bast's answer would be to use hash rather than pathname as hash will start after the /#/

Both are correct, just different ways of using $window.location.  Using hash, however, prevents you from having to deal with the path before the hash(#) in the url.

```
var path = $window.location.hash.split('/');
var path1 = path[1]; //example;
var path2 = path[2]; //url;
```

etc...

Answer (score 0):

Remember that Angular is still JavaScript. You can use native js functions to do that.

Check out the [location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) documentation.

You can use [location.pathname](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/pathname) to achieve what you want.

```
// http://myadress.com/#/example/url/here/param1
location.pathname.split('/') // --> ['', '#', 'example', 'url', 'here', 'param1']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$location` service which is part of angularjs:

```
var pathArray = $location.path().split('/');
//remove the first empty ''
pathArray.splice(0, 1);
```